# Why is the ngram-merge of srilm taking wrong input?

Tags: sh, kaldi, srilm

This is my first post here and sorry for my poor english.

I'm instantly working on Kaldi and srilm tools for my research, but I faced a strange problem while using ngram-merge to merge the 3-gram.count files generated by ngram-count.
(ngram-count and ngram-merge are two modules in srilm)

The code I used in my shell script is shown as follows:

```
ngram-merge \
 -write $dir_ngram/corpus_${ng}-gram.count \
 $dir_ngram/glsp_poj_tlu.txt_${ng}-gram.count /
 $dir_ngram/icorpus_tlu.txt_${ng}-gram.count /
 $dir_ngram/khkp_tlu.txt_${ng}-gram.count /
 $dir_ngram/nmtl_tlu.txt_${ng}-gram.count /
 $dir_ngram/total_tlu.txt_${ng}-gram.count /
 $dir_ngram/twbb_tlu.txt_${ng}-gram.count
```

while *$dir_ngram* simply stands for the directory of the .count files and *${ng}* is 3 here since I'm using trigram for my language model.

But when I run this part of code, errors occurred and they looks like this:

```
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/icorpus_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 1: unk: No such file or directory
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/icorpus_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/icorpus_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 2: `<unk> <unk> 11844000'
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/khkp_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 1: unk: No such file or directory
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/khkp_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/khkp_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 2: `<unk> <unk>    449400'
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/nmtl_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 1: unk: No such file or directory
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/nmtl_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/nmtl_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 2: `<unk> <unk>    13706200'
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/total_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 1: unk: No such file or directory
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/total_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/total_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 2: `<unk> <unk>   11155390'
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/twbb_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 1: unk: No such file or directory
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/twbb_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/kaldi/egs/simple_20190520/source/ngram/twbb_tlu.txt_3-gram.count: line 2: `<unk> <unk>    7575840'
```

It seems like **ngram-merge took the first line of the files as file name or directory**, since the unk symbol is the first line of every .count files (take *icorpus_tlu.txt_3-gram.count* for example):

```
<unk>   21952800
<unk> <unk>     11844000
<unk> <unk> <unk>       6161460
<unk> <unk> pó-tshî     660
<unk> <unk> pe̍h-liáu-kang       60
<unk> <unk> m̄-sī        3840
<unk> <unk> lîu-hîng    540
<unk> <unk> ē-sái       12900
<unk> <unk> uî-huat     1740
<unk> <unk> kín-tiunn   780
<unk> <unk> tâi-tiong-tshī      840
<unk> <unk> kuī 120
<unk> <unk> tsú-lâng    660
<unk> <unk> tsi̍t        38520
.
.
.
```

The unk symbol and the second line of the .count file appears in the first and third lines of the error message. I don't know why this is happening, because I think ngram-merge should only open the file and start to read the ngrams, not treating the content as a directory to open. Another strange thing is that **the "take content as directory" problem only occurs on the last five files**. The first file seems to have no reading or directory problem at all.

I know I could simply merge the corpus together since all the corpus are not too big, but I'm just a little curious about this problem. Does anybody know how to solve this？

Comment: You're using forward instead of backward slashes for line continuation, that's at least *a* problem.